# Define custom variable in config.php and access it in view

Tags: codeigniter, view, config

I have defined image_path in config.php and now need to access this variable in views like we use base_url().

Hos is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to extend the `url_helper`.  See the ["Extending Helpers"](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) section in the documentation.

In short, create a file name `MY_url_helper.php` in your `application/helpers` folder. (Assuming `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_'`, in your config file.)

Add the following method.

```
if ( ! function_exists('image_path'))
{
    function image_path() 
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->item('image_path');
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I modified this bit of code to simply access it a config_item('NAME'); But why can we simply access base_url like base_url() but not the custom config variables?

Comment: I guess they favored readability and extensibility over functionality.  After all, `image_path()` is cleaner than `config_item('image_path')`.  It's more readable, easier to test and it follows the framework's principles.  The first method allows you to add specific logic if needed in the future, while the `config_item('NAME')` makes it harder.  I can see `config_item('NAME')` as a nice utility method of your helper, I wouldn't use it in the view.

Answer (score 2):

Use constants.php, that's what it's for, this is out of my constants.php for image paths.

```
/*Constant paths*/
define('LOGO_PATH',APPPATH.'assets/images/manulogos/');
define('PROD_IMAGE_PATH',APPPATH.'../assets/images/prod_images/');
```

Then you just call the constant where you need it.

```
$imageName = $this->doUpload($control,PROD_IMAGE_PATH,$image,'all')
```